# How do I express a limit as a definite integral $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ and then evaluate the limit

Tags: integration

> How do I express a limit as a definite integral $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ and then evaluate the limit  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} ( \cos \frac{\pi}{2n} + \cos \frac{2 \pi}{2n} + ... + \cos \frac{k \pi}{2n} + .... + \cos \frac{(n-1) \pi}{2n} + \cos \frac{n\pi}{2n})$

What am I supposed to do with the limit as I have not encountered this type of problem relating definite integrals and limits before. Is this part of a discontinuous integrad?

I saw the answers and it states that

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_1^n \frac{1}{n} \sin \frac{k\pi}{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_1^n \frac{1}{n} \cos (\frac{k}{n} \frac{\pi}{2})$

How did they even arrive to these steps using which method?

Comment: Do you know to define the definite integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ as a limit?

Comment: I notice that the post linked which already answers the question is lacking some detail. Do you understand the solution?

Comment: @OgglieOstrich not really. I am not sure how to convert it

Comment: We define integration as:$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{n=0}^Nf(x_n)\Delta x,\: \Delta x = \frac{b-a}{N}, \: x_n= a + n \Delta x$$
$$\implies \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^Nf(x_n)\Delta x$$
So:
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^Nf(n\cdot \frac{1}{N})\frac{1}{N}$$ Now try substituting $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ and likewise for cos, then compare the values of the two integrals and relate the sums. Since your sum is from 0 to N instead of from 1 to N you might have to do a little extra reasoning.